# How do I find an element in an aura component from the client-side controller?

Tags: javascript, aura-framework

How do I get a reference to a child component of the current component from within the controller? For example:

```
<aura:component>
  <div class="container">
    <foo:myComponent />
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

In this case I would like to have a reference to `myComponent` from within this component's controller.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign an `aura:id` to your component and then use `find()`.

Component:

```
<aura:component>
  <div class="container">
    <foo:myComponent aura:id="myFancyComponent" />
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
init: function(cmp, event){
    var myComponent = cmp.find("myFancyComponent");
}
```